# Force Network Admin Dashboard to 1 column on wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, dashboard

I am wondering whether anyone knows how to force the dasboard layout to 1 column on a wordpress Multisite install for the Network Admin Dashboard

This is part of the solution but it does not force the number of columns to 1:

```
function so_screen_layout_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['dashboard-network'] = 1;
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'screen_layout_columns', 'so_screen_layout_columns' );
```

The following should force it but it does not work on the Network Admin Dashboard page, Anyone knows of a solution?

```
function so_screen_layout_dashboard() {
    return 1;
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'so_screen_layout_dashboard' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is how to overwrite these columns number settings in the *Screen Options* panel:

[image: columns]

### Network dashboard

When you change the number of columns in the screen options panel on the *network* dashboard page, you get the meta value of `screen_layout_dashboard-network`  saved into the `wp_usermeta` table:

[image: wp_usermeta]

In the `WP_Screen` class the columns number is fetched with:

```
get_user_option("screen_layout_$this->id")
```

where `$this->id` is `dashboard-network`.

When user options are fetched with `get_user_option( $option )` they are filtered through

```
return apply_filters("get_user_option_{$option}", $result, $option, $user);
```

In our case the user option is `screen_layout_dashboard-network` so the filter we are looking for is  `get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard-network`.

You should therefore try out:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard-network', 'number_of_columns' );

function number_of_columns( $nr ) {
    return 1;
}
```

### Site dashboard

Changing the columns number on the *site* dashboard page, we get the meta value of `screen_layout_dashboard` saved into the `wp_usermeta` table:

[image: wp_usermeta]

The filter that can be used here is:

```
  add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'number_of_columns' );
```

**ps:** The screen layout settings are only saved into the database when they are changed. So for a newly installed WordPress these settings are not in the database.

Comment: Thanks that's great works perfectly, just what I was looking for!

Comment: ok great, you should consider marking the answer as accepted to close the question, thanks ;-)